# How to access the variable declared in package init file when we use 'from package.subpackage import module'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

When we use `from package.subpackage import module`, how can we access the package and subpackage **init** file variables from the calling module?

Assuming `varname` is name of variable in the `__init__ file` from both the `package` and `package.subpackage`, how can we access them in the calling module? Example:

- `package.varname`
- `package.subpackage.varname`

I know that if we had used 'import package.subpackage.module' then the above is possible but I am getting name is not defined error when I try to do the same using the `from pkg.subpkg import mod` approach since the package is not in the local namespace (only module is).

Answer (score 3):

If a variable named `varname` is defined in the `__init__.py` module of a package named `package`, then we can access `varname` like this:

```
from package import varname
print(varname)
```

---

Similarly, if a variable named `varname` is defined in the `__init__.py` module of the subpackage named `subpackage` of a package named `package`, then we can access `varname` like this:

```
from package.subpackage import varname
print(varname)
```

---

To access both of them at the same time we should take care of the naming conflict like this:

```
from package import varname as package_varname
from package.subpackage import varname as package_subpackage_varname
print(package_varname)
print(package_subpackage_varname)
```

---

Also, `__init__.py` allows us to define any variable at the package level. Doing so is often convenient if a module defines something that will be imported frequently. This pattern promotes adherence to the Pythonic `flat is better than nested` philosophy.

An example:

Suppose our project structure looks like:

```
/project
  - __init__.py
  - file1.py
```

And our `file1.py` looks like:

```
message = 'hi there'
```

Then we can access it like:

```
from project.file1 import message
print(message)
```

Now to make it accessible like:

```
from project import message
```

In the `__init__.py` we can do:

```
from .file1 import message

__all__ = ['message']
```

Comment: And what about subpackage?

Comment: Same things, package.subpackage.variable

Comment: When we use 'from package.subpackage import module', how can we access the package and subpackage init file variables from the calling module?